# Simple 'for' loop to create divs

Tags: javascript

Why am I getting an 'undefined' at the top?

http://jsfiddle.net/oybz69xy/1/

```
var tiles;
function populateTiles(limit) {
for (var i=0; i< limit; i++) {
    tiles += "<div class='tile'>Tile</div>";
}
}
populateTiles(4);

$('#container').html(tiles);

<div id="container">


</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

Remember that the `+=` operator really means that

```
tiles += "<div class='tile'>Tile</div>";
```

gets expanded to

```
tiles = tiles + "<div class='tile'>Tile</div>";
```

The problem is that on the first loop iteration, `tiles` is `undefined` (because you haven't assigned anything to it), so you're concatentating `undefined` with a string. That's what's causing the behavior that you're seeing.

Initialize `tiles` to `""` first.

Answer (score 2):

Because you are using += on an undefined variable.  If you first line is `var tiles = "";` that should do the trick.

Answer (score 1):

Because the initial value of variable tiles is undefined. When an undefined value plus a string the string format of that value is used and that is the string "undefined". So you need to change your code to this;

```
var tiles = "";
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use array, instead of using concatenation in loop, refer below code which will improve the performance when the loop size is more

```
var tiles = [];
function populateTiles(limit) {
for (var i=0; i< limit; i++) {
    tiles.push("<div class='tile'>Tile</div>");
}
}
populateTiles(4);

$('#container').html(tiles.join(''));

<div id="container">


</div>
```